# How to update line renderer's start and end positions at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to connect two GameObject (**sphereObject0** and **sphereObject2**) with a line renderer **lineRenderer0_2** in a Unity3D project.

The line shows up fine at first. My problem is that I need the line renderer to update its start and end positions to match the positions of **sphereObject0** and **sphereObject2**.

For some reasons, my line renderer is absolutely static, and I can't find the way to make it adjust its start and end positions together with the spheres GameObjects eventually move around.

Here's my C# script, any idea about what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class autoCreateNetwork : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool sphereHasGravity = false;
    private Collider coll;
    private Renderer rend;
    private SpringJoint springJoint;
    public Material lines;

    GameObject sphereObject0;
    GameObject sphereObject2;
    LineRenderer lineRenderer0_2 ;

    void Start () {

        // Spawn a sphere and set it up
        sphereObject0 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphereObject0.transform.position = new Vector3(-10.2571400951f, 98.8977277884f, -19.9870244083f);
        Rigidbody sphereBody0 = sphereObject0.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        sphereBody0.mass = 1f;
        // Physics model
        coll = sphereBody0.GetComponent<Collider> ();
        PhysicMaterial material0 = new PhysicMaterial();
        material0.dynamicFriction = 1;
        coll.material = material0;
        coll.material.bounciness = .8f;
        // Render (color, smoothness, etc.)
        rend = sphereBody0.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.color = new Color32(171,166,164,255);
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Metallic", 0.0f);
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Glossiness", 0.0f);
        sphereBody0.useGravity = sphereHasGravity;
        sphereBody0.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);

        // Spawn a sphere and set it up
        sphereObject2 = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphereObject2.transform.position = new Vector3(-28.1943570987f, 89.5665878403f, 5.43686642264f);
        Rigidbody sphereBody2 = sphereObject2.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        sphereBody2.mass = 1f;
        // Physics model
        coll = sphereBody2.GetComponent<Collider> ();
        PhysicMaterial material2 = new PhysicMaterial();
        material2.dynamicFriction = 1;
        coll.material = material2;
        coll.material.bounciness = .8f;
        // Render (color, smoothness, etc.)
        rend = sphereBody2.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.color = new Color32(105,150,187,255);
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Metallic", 0.0f);
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Glossiness", 0.0f);
        sphereBody2.useGravity = sphereHasGravity;
        sphereBody2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);

        // Spawn a line and set it up
        GameObject line0_2 = new GameObject();
        LineRenderer lineRenderer0_2 = line0_2.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer0_2.material = lines;
        lineRenderer0_2.widthMultiplier = 0.0482773661501f;
        lineRenderer0_2.SetPosition(0, sphereObject0.transform.position);
        lineRenderer0_2.SetPosition(1, sphereObject2.transform.position);
        float alpha0_2 = .9f;
        Gradient gradient0_2 = new Gradient();
        gradient0_2.SetKeys(
            new GradientColorKey[] { new GradientColorKey(new Color32(171,166,164,255), 0.0f), new GradientColorKey(new Color32(105,150,187,255), 1.0f) },
            new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey(alpha0_2, 0.0f), new GradientAlphaKey(alpha0_2, 1.0f) }
        );
        lineRenderer0_2.colorGradient = gradient0_2;
        lineRenderer0_2.useWorldSpace = true;

    }

    void Update () {

            lineRenderer0_2.SetPosition(0, sphereObject0.transform.position);
            lineRenderer0_2.SetPosition(1, sphereObject2.transform.position);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is how you're assigning the `LineRenderer` with `AddComponent` to a new variable instead of your member variable.  The line here:

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer0_2 = line0_2.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

creates a new variable named `lineRenderer0_2` within the scope of `Start()` and hides the member variable when referenced elsewhere in that function.  Change the line to:

```
lineRenderer0_2 = line0_2.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

and it should work fine. As a side-node, it's common to name member variables with an "m_" prefix so you don't run into these issues.

Comment: This is fantastic (and really clear), thanks Gunther!